# IntelliJ how to change the PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, opencv, intellij-idea, homebrew, pythonpath

I've installed OpenCV using brew and added the following to my .bash_profile.

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

If I run Python on a "Terminal" I can import cv and cv2 without any issues.

However, when I try to do the same in IntelliJ 13 it doesn't recognize cv and cv2. I believe I've to modify PYTHONPATH in IntelliJ. I tried added setting the environment variable in the "IntelliJ IDEA -> Preferences -> Console -> Python Console -> Environment Variables) but it still doesn't work.

Any idea how to resolve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean when you run "Terminal" inside IntelliJ? What do you see when you enter `$ echo PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: No when I run Terminal/Command line shell on my Mac.

Comment: _"when I try to do the same in IntelliJ 13"_ - what exactly does it mean?

Comment: Is it necessary for you to use workstation Python installation for your project? Did you consider using virtualenv, it makes it really easy to manage packages.

Comment: By "when I try to do the same in IntelliJ 13"  I mean when i try to create a python project and create a .py file it doesn't find the cv and cv2. I've not tried virtualenv yet. Let me explore that option. Any good starting resource ?

Comment: It should be similar to PyCharm: [configuring python sdk](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-python-sdk.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to go into the run/debug configuration (i.e. edit configurations) and add PYTHONPATH to the  environment variables.  Mine already had PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1, so I went into dialog and added another entry for PYTHONPATH with value /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.

Hope that helps.